# Set alias php=/bin/php56 but today it has reverted to it's original path: /bin/php

Tags: php, console, export, alias

I'm using CentOS 7's remi and remi.safe repository. Remi installs PHP 5.4 to /bin/php and Remi Safe installs PHP 5.6 to /bin/php56.

When php is executed from the console, I want it to reference php56. Yesterday I set `alias php=/etc/php56` which seemed to have resolved the issue. Today, when I execute php -v it outputs:

```
PHP 5.4.16 (cli) (built: Jun 23 2015 21:17:27)
Copyright (c) 1997-2013 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.4.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2013 Zend Technologies
```

**Edit:**
I added `alias php=/bin/php56` to /home/{user}/.bashrc, logged out and logged back in and it did resolve it for that user.

Is it recommended, to set this globally, to do so via /etc/bashrc?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you need both version (5.4 and 5.6) ?

If you want a single version, enable "remi-php56" and yum update.

- See: http://rpms.remirepo.net/wizard/

Else run "scl enable php56 bash" before other commands to switch to php 5.6.

- See: http://blog.remirepo.net/post/2014/08/25/PHP-5.6-en-Software-Collection

Permanent solutions:

- in .bashrc => source /opt/remi/php56/enable
- ln -s /usr/bin/php56 /usr/bin/php

But again, if you need a single version, seems much more simpler to use "base" packages instead of "SCL" packages, designed for parallel installation of multiple versions.

Answer (score 0):

use this to run the PHP command from the command line

```
php -c /etc/php5.4/cli/php.ini -f scripts.php
```

Comment: If I were calling the script directly I could just use php56 as the command line command. My problem is that the bash script is calling drush which calls the PHP command directly which is why I need to map that command to php56

Comment: Are you asking for the output of env? Or to include it in my script. I haven't seen any understandable suggestions on how to use env to set the environment in a bash script.

Comment: release of "env" because it allows to list all the variables available to envirement